# How does US inflation impact dollarized nations?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, exchange-rates, foreign-exchange

For instance, would a high inflation rate on the US have any impact on countries that use the US dollar as their only legal tender, eg Ecuador or El Salvador?

I often hear that high US inflation will lead to high inflation in dollarized countries because of the US dollar losing purchasing power. While a lost of purchasing power in the US makes sense to me, it’s unclear to me why a loss of purchasing power would happen in other countries just because they US dollar is legal tender.

Comment: well, why does the US dollar have purchasing power in those countries? It's because they can go and buy stuff from the US, right? If the country was stable enough to not rely on the US providing backing value, it wouldn't need to be dollarized